# Why does python exit immediately when I pipe code in with echo but not with cat?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, echo, cat

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "print('Hello 1')" | python3

cat | python3 -u <<EOF
print('Hello 2')
EOF

echo "print('Hello 3')" | python3
```

This outputs

```
Hello 1
Hello 2
```

It will wait for me to press enter before printing the final `Hello 3`. It does this also using python's `-u` flag for unbuffered output.

Why does it do this for `cat` but not for `echo`?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with Python; `cat | cat <<EOF...` has the same effect.

Comment: The proper usage of cat is
    cat << EOF |
    ...
    EOF
    python3
see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046381/multiline-syntax-for-piping-a-heredoc-is-this-portable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You aren't using cat. You're using a here-doc, and cat is waiting for input separately. Just remove the `cat |` and try it again.

```
echo "print('Hello 1')" | python3
python3 -u <<EOF
print('Hello 2')
EOF
echo "print('Hello 3')" | python3
```

cat, the way you are using it, would pipe its stdin to its stdout, becoming the stdin for the proc on the other side of the pipe, but you also defined a `<<EOF` here-doc which takes precedence and ignores `cat`'s empty output.

cat is still waiting for *input* though. Once you hit return it (via OS magic) tries and realizes no one is listening on the pipe, and exits.

As an aside, you could also use a here-string, like this:

```
python3 <<< "print('Hello 2')"
```