# printf ignoring format in bash

Tags: bash, printf

This is a hackerrank problem:

[Compute the average](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/bash-tutorials---compute-the-average/problem)

As a brief summary, you need to sum up a predefined number of integers, then compute the average and print it with 3 digits precision.

I came up with the following code:

```
read number_of_ints;
sum=0

for number in $(seq 1 $number_of_ints); do 
    read number
    sum=$(($sum+$number))
done 

printf "%.3f\n" | bc -l <<< $sum/$number_of_ints
printf "%.3f\n" $(echo "$sum/$number_of_ints" | bc -l)
```

However, `printf "%.3f\n" | bc -l <<< $sum/$number_of_ints` blatantly ignores my format string and simply outputs it with 20 digit precision.
Meanwhile `printf "%.3f\n" $(echo "$sum/$number_of_ints" | bc -l)` does exactly what I want.

I get that the 20 precision digits are rooted in the fact that bc -l preloads a math library, but shouldn't printf "%.3f" still cut this down to three digits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code as given doesn't actually convey the output from `bc` to the command line of `printf`.

One way to span that gap would be with `xargs`:

```
bc -l <<<"$sum/$number_of_ints" | xargs printf '%.3f\n'
```

Comment: And this could dramatically fail on locales with a decimal comma rather than a decimal point, example fr_FR. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56909523/7939871 depending if the `printf` implementation expects `LC_NUMERIC` formatted arguments.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you aren't using `printf` correctly. `printf` expects a format string followed by as many strings as it gets, and it tries to parse them sanely according to the format. You have provided a format, but NO inputs, so it is likely just printing the requested newline to the pipe you set up behind it.

The `bc` now has two streams defined on stdin, and is ignoring the pipe in favor of the here-string.

```
printf "%.3f\n" | bc -l <<< $sum/$number_of_ints # two inputs
```

c.f. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50935974/why-does-python-exit-immediately-when-i-pipe-code-in-with-echo-but-not-with-cat) for a similar issue.

...But you don't need `printf` at all. See https://linux.die.net/man/1/bc

```
bc -l <<< "scale=3;$sum/$number_of_ints"
```

You could, in fact, code the whole *thing* in `bc`.

```
#!/usr/bin/bc
print "\nHow many numbers shall we average? "
scale=3
cnt=read()
c=cnt
while ( c ) {
  c=c-1
  print "\nEnter a number: "
  n=read()
  t=t+n
}
print "\nTotal: ", t, "\n"
print "Average: ", t/cnt, "\n"
quit
```

Then run it.

```
$: ./bcavg
bc 1.06.95
Copyright 1991-1994, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2004, 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type `warranty'.

How many numbers shall we average? 3

Enter a number: 2

Enter a number: 7

Enter a number: 9

Total: 18
Average: 6.000
```

Comment: nailed it. I noticed my brainfart shortly after asking the question :)

Answer (score 0):

A solution in pure `bash`, *without resorting to* `bc`

```
#!/bin/bash

sum=0
read n
for ((i = 0; i < n; ++i)); do read m; ((sum += m)); done

sign=1
if ((sum < 0)); then sign=-1; ((sum = -sum)); fi
m=$(( (sum * 10000 / n + 5) / 10 ))
printf '%d.%03d\n' $((m / 1000 * sign)) $((m % 1000))
```