# Pipe multiple verbatim lines into command in bash

Tags: bash, pipe, echo, cat, heredoc

I am trying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046381/multiline-syntax-for-piping-a-heredoc-is-this-portable) in `GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`:

```
$ echo <<EOF | cat
> 1
> 2
> 3
> EOF
```

I would have expected three lines of output (with `1`, `2`, `3`), but I receive an empty line. What am I missing (probably a simple mistake)? I am aware that this particular output can be produced in a simpler way; the example should serve as blueprint for a more substantial application.

Comment: No reason to use `cat` after `echo`. Just Replace `echo` with `cat` and remove pipe

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`echo` does not read from stdin. Maybe you are trying to do:

```
$ cat <<EOF | cat
> 1
> 2
> 3
> EOF
```

Which of course can be shortened to:

```
$ cat <<EOF
> 1
> 2
> 3
> EOF
```

Answer (score 7):

`echo` doesn't read from standard input, but it doesn't need to. You can embed newlines in a string.

```
$ echo '1
> 2
> 3' | cat
```

You can also use `printf` to output each word on a separate line:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 1 2 3
1
2
3
```

Or use a command group to pipe the output of multiple commands as a whole, which is useful if you have something more complicated than a group of simple `echo` commands, but as an example:

```
{
  echo 1
  echo 2
  echo 3
} | cat
```